# How to pass value in a javascript from PHP or HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I want to pass variable to google map script from php or html.
but this is not working.

```
<?php
$x1=58.983991;
$y1=5.734863;
?>

<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng($x1,$y1);
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $x1; ?>,<?php echo $y1; ?>);
```

You can open PHP anywhere on the webpage until and unless the extension of the page is `.php`.

Comment: So much Thanks.... I wish I could vote you, Unluckly I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x1=58.983991;
$y1=5.734863;

?>


<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $x1?>,<?php echo $y1?>);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use echo Short tag of php to print values .

```
 <?php
    $x1=58.983991;
    $y1=5.734863;
    ?>        
    <script>

    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$x1; ?>,<?=$y1;?>);
    </script>
```